# Availability and Atomic update in CQRS

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices, cqrs, debezium

I am trying to implement CQRS design using the following components:

Database —>Debezium (CDC) —>Kafka —->Kafka Stream(read view updater) —>Read View

The database can be MySQL or PostgreSQL, and Kafka Streams could act as event processor/read view updater which does the necessary transformation on the cdc events and update the read view.

- How to achieve high availability with the following configuration? (I heard CDC streams stops once the source DB or Debezium itself goes down)
- Is it possible to achieve exactly once/at least once event processing? In case of failure it is possible to get duplicate message which might lead to same data storing in read side again. What can be done to achieve idempotence in CQRS configuration?
- Does anyone have a different architectural suggestion or technology stack for implementing CQRS with high availability and atomic update using exactly once/at least once message handling?

Answer (score 1):

CDC will stop when the source DB stops.  CDC stopping will not affect the read view's availability.

Exactly-once updating of the read view (which is what one almost certainly cares about) is not possible in the general case.  If it's possible for the stream consuming from Kafka and updating the read view to atomically commit the offset of the message as part of updating the read view, then an exactly-once update can be guaranteed.  As far as Debezium potentially publishing duplicate change records (which it may do: idempotent production AFAIK has not yet made it in), depending on the DB the change records may have a `before` field in the payload.  This field can be used to validate that the change is applied from a state which corresponds to the read view (and ignore inapplicable changes).

You may find it easier to implement an idempotent projection to a read model if the write model is event-sourced vs. update-in-place: the events will typically have a per-entity sequence number which can make "effectively-once" (at-least-once with an idempotent consumer) easier.